# Tailwind CSS grid span (unexpected behavior)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to do this in my Next.js project:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/coz07Km10V

But the result is different, is pushing the block idk why, here's the reproduction:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/distracted-ben-53gsl4?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A1%2C14

It seems that Next.js overwrite or change the native behavior of that grid property. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's actually the Tailwind playground that's broken here - if I replace `<div class="col-span-2 bg-purple-500"/>` with `<div class="col-span-2 bg-purple-500"></div>` then the two examples behave the same: https://play.tailwindcss.com/gGtlBynuCo It just coincidentally happens to be broken in a way that the final output is what you wanted

To fix it, you'll want to put the `img` inside the first grid element instead, like so: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Vd4vDz1SuM

Your method doesn't work because `col-span-2` makes the element occupy two columns in the grid layout, but doesn't affect *which* columns it occupies - those are still assigned from left to right. In other words, the first div will occupy columns 1 and 2 of the grid, and the second occupies columns 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML doesn't exist the concept of **Div** self-closed tag:

***"In XML,  would be a self-closing div, but not in HTML. In HTML,  doesn't self-close because "div" isn't on the list of elements that can never have children."***

So to correct your code, you will need to use other techniques, like using **Absolute** and **col-start**:

```js
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-protop-lavander h-[400px]">
      <div className="grid auto-rows-[370px] grid-cols-4">
        <div className="col-span-2 col-start-1 col-end-4 bg-green-500" />
        <div className="absolute col-span-2 col-start-1 col-end-4">
          <img
            className="block object-cover opacity-50 h-[370px] w-full"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568092806323-8ec13dfa9b92?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
            alt="eg"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from Wongjn (tailwind contributor):

in HTML (i.e. the Tailwind Play) does not mean  as it does in React – it behaves as an open tag only, .

Thus, to make the equivalent of the CodeSandbox project in Tailwind Play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/gGtlBynuCo

Or to make the equivalent of the Tailwind Play in the CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/https-github-com-tailwindlabs-tailwindcss-discussions-12461-7nwt8f?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A6%2C11